# Finding max flow between two nodes on graph

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph

I'm trying to find all paths between two nodes on a graph using recursive depth first search. The graph also contains cycles so I use an array to keep track of the nodes that I've visited. I would then like to choose the path with the max flow.

I was wondering what the best data structure to use for storing the paths was. My graph will have at most 1000 nodes and at most 10000 roads between nodes.

My initial guess was an array of pointers to a list containing a path, although the space complexity to store the array and the time complexity needed to traverse the array to find the path with max flow would be huge.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your rules are for unique paths;

```
typedef std::list<int> Path;
typedef std::list<Path> Paths;

class Node {
public:
    Node() : visited(false) { }
    bool visited;
    Path edge;
};

const int max_nodes = 1000;
Node nodes[max_nodes];

bool visitNode(Path &out,int node,int target) {
    if (node == target)
        return true;
    Node& n = nodes[node];
    if (n.visited) 
        return false;
    n.visited = true;
    for (Path::iterator it = n.edge.begin(); it != n.edge.end(); it++) {
        if (visitNode(out,*it,target)) {
            out.push_back(node);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void resetNodes() {
    for (int i = 0; i < max_nodes; i++) 
        nodes[i].visited = false;
}

Paths findPaths(int node,int target) {
    resetNodes()
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finding the path with the *largest flow capacity* is equivalent to finding the path for which the edge with lowest capacity is maximised. So you can use some pathfinding algorithm and extend it to keep track of the lowest edge capacity seen on a path. For DFS, you can even keep a lower bound, the largest capacity path you have seen so far. You then need not consider any edge with less capacity while searching, because any path with such an edge cannot have higher capacity than the path you already found.